# How to get the time stamp of each frame of a video in PYTHON and save the image with its timestamp?

Tags: python, algorithm, timestamp, google-colaboratory, video-processing

I am working with video frames and its data processing. I am extracting frames from input video and saving them into a directory like so-

```
import cv2
import os

cam = cv2.VideoCapture("/content/AI_PPT_video.mp4")
  
try:     
    if not os.path.exists('data'):
        os.makedirs('data')
except OSError:
    print ('Error')

currentframe = 0
  
while(True):
    ret,frame = cam.read() 
    if ret:
        name = './data/frame' + str(currentframe) + '.jpg'
        print (name)
        cv2.imwrite(name, frame)  
        currentframe += 1
    else:
        break
  
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The images are getting saved with its name being the Nth frame. Instead, I want the name of each saved image in the folder to be the video-timestamp (timelog) in the format 00:00:00. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `datetime` library to change the file name to timestamp.

```
import datetime as dt
...

current_time = dt.timedelta(seconds=0)

while(True):
    ret,frame = cam.read() 
    if ret:
        name = './data/frame' + str(current_time) + '.jpg'
        cv2.imwrite(name, frame)  
        current_time += dt.timedelta(seconds=1)
    else:
        break
```

If you do not want to add only 1 second per frame, then check out the fps (frame per second) of your video and change `dt.timedelta(seconds=1)` to `dt.timedelta(microseconds=1000000/fps)` or `dt.timedelta(milliseconds=10/fps)`

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the video-timestamp by dividing the frame number by the `fps`.
The `fps` you can get this way:

```
fps = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
```

Than you format the time you calculated in the format you want and use it for your file name.